# Why does grid traveller have a time complexity of 2^(n+m)?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

**Grid Traveller**

- Returns the number of ways to traverse from the top-left to the bottom-right corner of a n x m grid. An example of a recursive function would look like this

```
def grid_traveller(n,m):
    if n == 0 or m == 0: return 0
    if n == 1 and m == 1: return 1
    return grid_traveller(n-1,m), grid_traveller(n,m-1)
```

An example:

```
         2,2
       /     \
    1,2       2,1
   /   \      /  \
0,2     1,1  1,1  2,0
```

While I can come up with the solution I'm confused about the depth and time complexity. The depth is supposedly n+m because only either n or m can decrease at a time, so it will take n+m steps to reach (0,0). That sounds logical, but **what does depth even mean?** In this case, the tree has a height of 3 (instead of 2+2=4) and the number of recursion calls is 2 ((1,2) and (2,1)), so **what does depth tell us?** I used to think that depth = height of recursion tree (at least for a single input), but I'm not sure if I have the right idea.

I think if I understood a little more about depth I might figure out why the time complexity is 2^(n+m), but do feel free to explain on that too.

Comment: How come your recursive calls only take one argument? Also, the first two cases return an integer, the recursion returns a pair?!

Comment: oops, my bad missed that out. It should be right now.

Comment: *“I used to think that depth = height of recursion tree”* Yep, it is, in this context. In what way is that failing you now?

Comment: @Ry- because the height of recursion tree in this case seems to be 3 and not 4, for a few other examples I couldn't get height of tree = depth too

Comment: O(2^(1+n+m)) = O(2 \* 2^(n+m)) = O(2^(n+m)). The complexity is the same even if the actual stack depth is different from the tree you’re analyzing by a constant offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confused by a problem and it wasn't clear to me what I didn't understand. I think the thing that knocked me out of it was Ry-'s comment.

> The complexity is the same even if the actual stack depth is different from the tree you’re analyzing by a constant offset.

When I posted this question I rejected the idea that height = n+m (along with some other self-confusion that I now have no idea why) but didn't notice the simple pattern that the examples I drafted all had height = n + m -1.

So now that I've re-accepted that depth = height of tree = n+m, I can go on to comfortably accept the time complexity. For completeness sake, here's my explanation:

Recursion depth is also known as the the height of the recursion tree.
The time complexity is 2^(n+m) because for every level down the tree, the number of function calls we have to make doubles (1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16).

For a tree of height 3 (in this example), we have to make 2^3=8 calls (count the nodes above if you're confused!).
For a tree of height (n+m-1), we have to make 2^(n+m-1)~=2^(n+m) calls (because constants are insignificant when n+m approaches infinity).

Answer (score -1):

Will try to give more intuitive explanation. For eg : n = 3 and m = 3;
grid is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

So options starting from 0,0 will be like this

```
            1
         /     \
        4       2
      /  \     /  \
     7    5   5   3   
    / \
   8   ...
  /
 9
```

Too lazy to make the whole tree. but the depth you can see is n+m-1

or 3 + 3 -1 = 5 in this case
therefore the complexity to traverse this trie

= O(nodes)

= O(2^(n+m-1) - 1)

~ O(2^(n+m))

P.S please feel free to correct this if required. :)

Answer (score -1):

Time Complexity will be O(2^(m+n-2))but the constant will be neglected. so  it becomes O(2^(m+n)). You can compute this by yourself. There are two calls for every function calling , U can see it while drawing recursion tree . for each level there are 2 raise to the power calls if there are k levels then there will be 2^k calls & this will be equivalent to 2^(m+n-2)). so we can say the final complexity will be O(2^(m+n-2)) after ignoring -2 consstant.